# How do I remove lead paint?

Tags: paint-removal, lead

Recently purchased a grade 2 property. It has very nice shutters (original but they are seal shut with the amount of paint and I’m hoping to strip them and bring them back to life. Done a lead test and came back positive. How can I strip them? What is the best tips and tricks and how dangerous is it?

Comment: You will need to contain all the lead paint you remove, no dumping it down a drain.  All dust made also needs to be contained, so no sanding outdoors, unless in a sealed building/tent.  Need also to prevent breathing or ingesting any fumes or dust by you or anyone nearby.  There are professionals that do this, it is usually not a DIY job.

Comment: Plus, in most jurisdictions, you need a permit to (legally) remove lead paint.

Comment: Call a professional. This is one of the DIY situations you shouldn't undertake. If you do it wrong, you might not realize it, but then the damage will be done.

Comment: As for danger, young children should be in the next county till all the lead is removed completely.  For an old fart, who cares, but not good to be around either.

Comment: I bet it would be cheaper to throw them away and replace them than to remove the lead paint.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of job in renovations, we used to bring the doors and shutters to a company that dunked them into a chemical bath that removed all the paint. This gave excellent results, the wood ended up smooth and "like new" with only a few traces of paint remaining. They handled disposal of hazardous waste. Using past tense because they went out of business, but you'll probably find someone in your area to do this.

I'd recommend doing the same. Breathing lead paint dust isn't very good for your health.

You can also do it yourself, but the cost of the paint stripper and waste disposal will probably be more.

Comment: I used a company like that as well. If the item is glued then be careful as some can come unglued. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to remove lead paint. The biggest issue with lead paint would be removing it and exposing yourself to the dust and debris. I would encourage you to paint over it.

Comment: The OP's problem is the over painting stopping the shutters from moving.  OP does not want more paint.  Your answer is good for most other cases.